# Why doesn't it add proprieties inside of object?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, object, dynamic

I need to insert dynamically proprieties inside of "voci_agg" object that is inside "sm" object:
sm = { voci_agg: {} };

The issue is that when i try to add, it will return:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'm_motore-radiatore' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'm_motore-radiatore' of undefined

(m_motore-radiatore is retrieved from DB and added dynamically to "sm.voci_agg").

This is the code interested:

**schemamasse-comp.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let voce of voci; let i = index">
 <td class="align-middle">{{ voce.descrizione }}</td>
 <td>
  <input [(ngModel)]="sm.voci_agg[voce.m_model]" class="form-control" (keyup)="cal_m_utile($event)" type="number" step="any" min="0" name="{{ voce.m_model }}" id="{{ i }}"/>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input [(ngModel)]="sm.voci_agg[voce.d_model]" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" min="0" name="{{ voce.d_model }}" id="{{ i }}"/>
 </td>
 <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="del_voce($event)" id="{{ i }}"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

**schemamasse-comp.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { VociAggiuntive } from './vociaggiuntive.model';

// Modal "VOCI AGGIUNTIVE"
@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Voci aggiuntive</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row form-group text-center p-1 bg-dark text-white">
        <div class="col"><label for="descrizione"><h6>Descrizione</h6></label></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="submit_add_voce()">Aggiungi</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="get_voci_aggiuntive()">Aggiorna</button></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="submit_delete_voce()">Elimina</button></div>
      </div>
      <div *ngFor="let voce of voci_aggiuntive" class="row form-group text-center p-1">
        <div class="col btn-group btn-group-toggle"><label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary"><input ngbButton (change)="check_voce($event)" type="checkbox" value="{{ voce._id }}"/>{{ voce.descrizione }}</label></div>
        <div *ngIf="selected[voce._id] === true" class="col"><i class="fas fa-check fa-2x text-success"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Crea nuova voce</button></div>
    <div *ngIf="response === true" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>{{ message }}</strong>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="response === false" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>{{ message }}</strong>
    </div>
    `
})
export class VociAggiuntiveComponent{
  public voci_aggiuntive: VociAggiuntive[] = [];
  response; message; arr_check = []; selected = {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private modalService: NgbModal, public activeModal: NgbActiveModal){
    this.get_voci_aggiuntive();
  }

  get_voci_aggiuntive(){
    this.http.get<VociAggiuntive[]>(`${origin}/api/get_voci_aggiuntive`).subscribe(res => { this.voci_aggiuntive = res });
  }
  check_voce(event){
    let i;
    if(event.target.checked === true){ this.arr_check.push(event.target.value); this.selected[event.target.value] = true; }
    else if (event.target.checked === false){
      for(i = 0; i < this.arr_check.length; i += 1){
        if(event.target.value === this.arr_check[i]){ this.arr_check.splice(i, 1); this.selected[event.target.value] = false; } 
      }
    }
  }
  open(){
    this.modalService.open(CreaNuovaVoceComponent, { backdrop: true, centered: true, scrollable: true, size: 'lg' });
  }
  submit_add_voce(){
    this.http.post<VociAggiuntive[]>(`${origin}/api/load_voci_aggiuntive`, this.arr_check).subscribe(res => { this.activeModal.close(res); });
  }
  submit_delete_voce(){
    let sinplu = this.arr_check.length;
    if(confirm('Sei sicuro di voler eliminare le voci selezionate? \n\n !!! ATTENZIONE !!! \nL\'operazione non è reversibile!')){
      this.http.post<VociAggiuntive[]>(`${origin}/api/delete_voci_aggiuntive`, this.arr_check)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if(sinplu < 2){ this.message = 'Voce aggiuntiva eliminata'; }
        else{ this.message = 'Voci aggiuntive eliminate'; }
        this.response = true;
        this.get_voci_aggiuntive();
        setTimeout (() => {
          this.response = undefined;
        }, 2000);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.response = false;
        this.message = 'Errore Server Interno';
      });
    }
  }
}

// Main component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-schema-masse',
  templateUrl: './schemamasse-comp.component.html'
})
export class SchemaMasseComponent{
  sm = { voci_agg: {} };
  voci_aggiuntive(){
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(VociAggiuntiveComponent, { centered: true, scrollable: true, size: 'lg' });
    modalRef.result.then((res) =>{
      if(res){
        for(let index in res){
          this.sm.voci_agg[res[index].m_model] = 0;
          this.sm.voci_agg[res[index].d_model] = 0;
          this.voci.push(res[index]);
          console.log(this.sm);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  del_voce(event){
    this.voci.splice(event.target.id, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing `m_motore-radiatore` like `m_motore-radiatore = {}` ?

Comment: no, because m_motore-radiatore have to be added inside sm.voci_agg, so i can call it: sm.voci_agg['m_motore-radiatore'].

The structure is: sm{ key1: 123, key2: 123, voci_agg{ m_motore-radiatore: 123 }}

Comment: I can't totally understand the code, can you please tell me where is the code's line that throw that error?

Comment: You initializing sm = { voci_agg: {} }; then this.sm.voci_agg[res[index].m_model].

Comment: (Aggiungo un consiglio: abituati a scrivere codice in inglese)

Comment: Jacopo Sciampi this is the line code where it gives me error: this.sm.voci_agg[res[index].m_model] = 0;

Comment: Have you tried debugging just to be sure that this.sm.voci_agg is not null inside that function?

Comment: You are trying to assign a value (`m_mode`) to an object that is null. Doing `this.sm.voci_agg[res[index]] = {}` and then `this.sm.voci_agg[res[index].m_model] = 0;` should solve the issue. (Un consiglio che ti do io è quello di non abbreviare i nomi, è difficile capire cosa vuoi fare non conoscendo il progetto, ed i nomi che hai scelto non aiutano).

Comment: Federico Provenziani yes, i've tried everything, also tried to add a propriety so is not null.

Comment: I was hoping it was a variable scope issue. If it isn't i haven't any other idea, sorry.

Comment: Jacopo Sciampi "res" is an array of objects.
(Ok, grazie del consiglio)

Comment: Federico Provenziani (Si, al momento ho tradotto solo alcune scritte in inglese)

Comment: I'm stubborn, so please try following: add const self = this; just under voci_aggiuntive(){. Then call inside the callback self.sm.voci_agg[res[index].m_model] = 0;

Comment: Federico Provenziani i've tried but print the same error:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'm_motore-radiatore' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'm_motore-radiatore' of undefined
    at schemamasse-comp.component.ts:183

Comment: Ok, i'm givin up.

Comment: The issue is voci_agg property that it sees as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i had to declare a temporary object, insert all properties that i need to use and assign to primary object the temporary object:

```
voci_aggiuntive(){
 const modalRef = this.modalService.open(VociAggiuntiveComponent, { centered: true, scrollable: true, size: 'lg' });
    modalRef.result.then((res) =>{
      if(res){
        for(let index in res){
          for(let key in res[index]){ if(key === 'm_model' || key === 'd_model'){ this.tmp_obj_voci[res[index][key]] = 0; }}
          this.sm.voci_agg = this.tmp_obj_voci;
          this.voci.push(res[index]);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```